# It is possible to call orchestration runner from another orchestration?

Tags: salt-stack

Im trying to call some complex orchestration, from another orchestration run.

As usual in salt there is no example in doc, https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.saltmod.html#salt.states.saltmod.runner

It is possible? How to pass parameters?
Im testing this on simple example for simplification, but it ends with error:

```
 test_ping_all_servers_runner:
   salt.runner:
    - name:
      - state.orchestrate
    - kwargs: {
        name: orch.test_all_servers
      }
```

file orch.test_all_servers.sls looks like this and it works calling separately:

```
test_ping_sld:
  module.run:
    - name: test.ping
    - tgt: 'G@role:sld and G@sld:mode:admin'
    - tgt_type: compound
```

I got this error message:

```
[DEBUG   ] Unable to fire args event due to missing __orchestration_jid__
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded saltutil.runner
[ERROR   ] An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 1746, in call
    **cdata['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1704, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/states/saltmod.py", line 654, in runner
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/saltutil.py", line 1218, in runner
    full_return=full_return)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/runner.py", line 141, in cmd
    full_return)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/client/mixins.py", line 225, in cmd
    self.functions[fun], arglist, pub_data
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1087, in __getitem__
    func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 96, in __getitem__
    if self._load(key):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1494, in _load
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```